# Add single column to a glue table from java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to modify existing Glue table columns and adding a single extra column to the table using Java sdk. 
 It requires passing [TableInput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/glue/model/TableInput.html) object to [UpdateTableRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/UpdateTableRequest.html). However creating TableInput requires having almost all existing information the table even though just an extra column is to be added. There is no method to convert [Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/UpdateTableRequest.html) object to TableInput. 
 Is there a better and cleaner way to do simple modifications to existing table like add new column or new parameter ?

Comment: the UpdateTableRequest you are pointing is for a DDB table.You can simply do a get table and pass the same output as input to updatetable in glue with required changes.

Comment: Yes, that's the current way I found. but that's too long tho. Requires something like tableInput.withName(table.getName()).withTableType(table.getTableType()).withStorageDescriptor(table.getStorageDescriptor()).withPartitionKeys(table.getPartitionKeys()).withParameters(table.getParameters())......

Comment: and all remaining field may also need to be added. Is there a better way ?

Comment: all you need to is just append a column to existing ['StorageDescriptor']['Columns']

Comment: Can you share a code snippet please ?